# Firebase cloud function reads only one of many datasnapshots from database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, promise, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I am reading from Firebase Database through CLI to get a list of members whom I will send a notification. The database is searched through orderByChild satisfying certain condition. The problem is that the notification is sent to only one user although there are many uses satisfying the condition. I believe that the function reads only one user from the database. Could be a problem of improper user of async-await. Can someone help. Here is my code:

```
export const myfunction = functions.database.ref('/********/{*****Id}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

const *****Id = context.params.orderId
const mobile = snapshot.child('******').val()
const timeCreated = new Date

const ***DataBase = admin.database().ref()
const myRef = ***Base.child('users').orderByChild('****').equalTo('****')

const array:any = []
const snapshot2 = await myRef.once('value')
snapshot2.forEach(child => array.push(child))


for(const child of array){
    const key = child.key
    console.log(key)
    if(key!==null){
            const token = child.child('token').val()
            const payload = 
            {
                data:
                {
                    title: "Alert: ****",
                    body: "*****",
                    icon: "default"
                }
            }

            const options = {
                priority: "high"
            }

            await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload, options)
        }

}
})
```

basically array.push(child) creates only one member in array[]

Answer (score 0):

After much deliberation I could find my own solution. The problem was not with the promise or async-await. It was with the snapshot2.forEach(child => array.push(child)) method. Here unless we specifically mention a return false, the forEach loop was exiting without going through the entire process. Hence the solution is something like this:

```
snapshot2.forEach((child: any) => {
    array.push(child)
    return false
})
```

Things are now working as per expectation